# - ERROR: No postgresql version uses the port 5432/tcp

Tags: installation, openvas

I'm doing Complete ethical hacker bootcamp on Udemy, and following seos3c.com tips for Top things to do after installing Kali Linux. On trying to do everything like the instructor(besides I have postgresql (15) 16 due to newer version), I get these errors when I run 'Sudo gvm-setup' after (hopefully) having installed Openvas:

-ERROR: No postgresql version uses the port 5432/tcp

-ERROR: libgvmd needs postgresql 16 to use the port 5432

-ERROR: use pg_upgradecluster to update your postgresql cluster

Did I forget to mention I am a complete noob(see username :0) ? An option can be to tell me to go back to an earlier snapshot of Kali, and try again. But I am going to get the same problems, so I will need some instructions.

Thanks.